# How can I perform an hybrid multibox search on Exchange from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, search, exchange-hybrid

I have to adapt a script that do "OnPromises" searches a hybrid context. I used the `New-MailboxSearch` cmdlet to implement this script.
The script searches all the indicated mailboxes and copies the results into another mailbox account. Searches can be edited.

The options I have contemplated are:

- `New-ComplianceSearch` cmdlet. I don't know how to set an email folder to copy the results.
- `Search-Mailbox` cmdlet. It would not be possible to edit the searches later.

Besides, is it possible to do this search in one step? That is, use a single cmdlet without having to do the search first on the mailboxes online and then on the mailboxes onpremises

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell pipeline to search all mailboxes:

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited |Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'yourquery'`

it isn't new solution, but still works fine in 2010-2016 exchange.
You can use `get-mailbox -filter` key to find certain mailboxes in the fast way.

About `New-ComplianceSearch` - check this link:
https://4sysops.com/archives/search-and-delete-exchange-email-using-powershell/